# jQuery adding to css element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the id of my element. I need to add a given value (determined by a variable in the javascript) to one of the element's css attributes.  I.e. given an element `id=my_id` how do I add `x` to that element's `margin-top` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = 20;
$('#my_id').css('margin-top', function(index, value) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value)))
        return x;

    return parseInt(value) + x
});
```

Comment: This will fail if `parseInt(value)` returns `NaN`. You should add some sort of protection against that possibility.

Comment: Björn - Unfortunately, with your edit it will now return the value of `x` 100% of the time. You'll never get to the second return statement because `isNaN(value)` will always evaluate to `true`. The reason for this is that when `margin-top` does have a value, the `value` parameter will give the size in `px` (like `10px`), which is not a number.

Comment: ...If jQuery always gives a `px` value, then your original `parseInt()` answer would work. I'd do some careful testing before relying on that, and then would still probably have a safety net.

Answer (score 2):

```
var inc = 20;
var mt = parseInt($('#my_id').css('margin-top').replace('px',''));
$('#my_id').css('margin-top',(mt+inc)+"px");
```

This assumes, of course, you always use px for margin-top values. I've used this reliably for quite some time.

Comment: methodin - This will work, but you really don't need to do a `.replace('px','')`, because this will not interfere with `parseInt()`. Also you don't need to add `"px"` in your `.css()` call, since that is assumed when you pass an integer. Last thing is that you should consider caching the `#my_id` element instead of selecting it twice in a row.

Comment: All valid points. Has parseInt always behaved like that? I must be thinking of my ie6 javacript days.

Comment: methodin - I belive it is IE6 safe, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to double check. Certainly doesn't hurt much to have that safeguard in there. Just may be unnecessary. :o)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to [use jQuery's `.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but give it a duration of `0`. This allows you to send the `+=` operator as a string, and concatenate the value of `x`.

```
var x = 50;

$('#my_id').animate({marginTop: '+=' + x}, 0);
```

Another way would be to pass a function as the second parameter to [jQuery's `.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/). The return value will be the current value plus `x`. *This requires jQuery 1.4 or later.*

```
var x = 50;

$('#my_id').css('margin-top', function(i,val) { return (parseInt(val) || 0) + x; });
```